# SSIS Error Output Script and Insert Reuse

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have an SSIS  Data flow that does a select and determines if it should insert or update a record.  For the Select, insert and update I have an Error Output, attached to a script component and then OLE DB Command to insert the error into the table. All insert to the same logging table.  I have a column hard coded to tell me which DML action was occurring so I know where the error was. While this all works well, I have to code this action three times every package. I spend more time coding these error outputs than the actual logic.

One thing to add, I am using 'On Error Redirect Row".  If I set the task to ignore error it does not log the error for each record to the sysssislog table for the ONERROR setting. I want the flow to continue on error.

Is there a way to create a reuseable error output and log process that I can reuse on all actions in a data flow? Ideally I would have be able to attach as many error outputs as I want to the same process.

I have logging enabled in SSIS itself but this method gets me what I want in a format that is very easy to read and report.  Open to all suggestions. Using SQL Server 2014. Thanks

Comment: Can't you point all three error outputs to the same script and put an OR on the precedence constraints?

Comment: When I attempt to link multiple error outputs to a transformation script I get the error "OperationFailure - All the available inputs on the target component are connected to outputs" I am thinking it might be possible to add more inputs for the script but I was hoping it would be more dynamic since I do not have a fixed number of inputs per flow. I was hoping for something more dynamic.

Comment: I take that back, it is not possible to add more inputs to the script, only more outputs. So that does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking script task in the control flow, but you are in a dataflow.   You could pass all the error outputs to a UNION ALL transformation, and then pass the output of that to the script transformation.  It wouldn't be dynamic though, you would have to specify what to do with the missing columns from the different inputs.

Comment: There is potential here. It will not let me log which path hit the error though.  I have an error on the union as well that I need to look into.  I will update when I find something. Thanks

Comment: I deleted all the extra columns from the Union All and it did work.  However I need to add a derived column to each flow before it hits the Union All to indicate which flow it came from.  While it works its not much better than what I had before. I am still coding 6 steps and I coded 6 steps before.

Comment: Well instead of derived column transformations, could you put the new columns in the SELECT statements in the source components?  Other than that, your options look pretty limited; even script components can't have multiple inputs, so the UNION ALL looks like your best hope.

Comment: I considered that, I would have to add a field to my query for each path, union them all together and use that. It is an option. Still not ideal, and not sure if worth all the work compared to what I was doing. Was hoping for a more elegant solution but its looking like SSIS does not do that...